# Having problems with displaying a grid in HTML on a page using PHP and MYsql

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have been working on a project over the last few months, starting with simply coding in HTML, and then progressively adding PHP / Mysql / Java to the page (not on JAVA yet). Now, the page that I have does work, but I have a problem that I have not been able to solve.

In an effort to make my webpage responsive, I am using both a grid and flexbox. Currently I am adding MYsql database data to the webpage so it can retrieve data from a database. I have been able to make the connection and retrieve the stored table data (A multidimensional array), but the problem I am having is adding this table data to the grid. Here is my code for the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./css/flex_nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Flex Nav</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sigmar+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

        <header class="header">    
            <h1>INF7440</h1>
        </header>

    <nav>

        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="logo"><a href="#">BGAles</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="item button"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li class="item button secondary"><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
            <li class="toggle"><span class="bars"></span></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

        <aside class="aside-1">
            <h2>Aside 1</h2>
            <p>Pellentesque id ante quis lacus condimentum suscipit eu quis justo. Nam cursus sollicitudin tortor, ut porta orci placerat a.</p>
        </aside>

        <article class="article">
            <h2>Article</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ac sem dignissim, porttitor sem sed, eleifend dolor. Cras enim ex, rhoncus in euismod eget, placerat vel enim.</p>
        </article>

        <aside class="aside-2">
            <h2>Aside 2</h2>
            <p>Duis id lobortis sem. Pellentesque efficitur lacus nec condimentum auctor. Vivamus est purus, feugiat sit amet pellentesque et, semper quis lacus.</p>
        </aside>

        <aside class="aside-3">
            <h2>Aside 3</h2>
            <p>Fusce mattis leo augue, a cursus lorem elementum at. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        </aside>

        <article class="article-2">
            <h2>Article 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ac sem dignissim, porttitor sem sed, eleifend dolor. Cras enim ex, rhoncus in euismod eget, placerat vel enim.</p>
        </article>

        <aside class="aside-4">
            <h2>Aside 4</h2>
            <p>Etiam nec nisl quam. Nunc malesuada lectus urna, ut sagittis felis dapibus et. Aliquam augue purus, ultrices vel imperdiet et, interdum eu dui.</p>
        </aside>

    <section class="mysql-results">

        

        <footer class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li>This is</li>
                <li>A footer</li>
            </ul>
        </footer>

    </div>



    <!--Loading jquery library dynamically -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Adding additional jquery script to page -->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
                if($(".item").hasClass("active")) {
                    $(".item").removeClass("active");
                } else {
                    $(".item").addClass("active");
                }
            })
        });
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

As I said, the MYsql connection works; its the grid I am concerned about. When I go to my page and inspect, my grid is not being recognized as a grid. When I do so in Firefox, it recognizes everything in the wrapper element as being a part of a grid, but not the section "mysql-results". When the page displays on firefox, the mysql-results show up on the page under my footer. When I inspect in Chrome, it does not recognize a grid at all, but the section (mysql-results) displays correctly, inside the grid that I have laid out in my CSS. Here is my CSS for the page:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vw;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(194, 194, 214);
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header"
                        "nav nav nav"
                        "aside-1 article aside-2"
                        "aside-3 article-2 aside-4"
                        "mysql-results mysql-results mysql-results"
                        "footer footer footer";
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

.mysql-results {
    grid-area: mysql-results;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    border: thin solid #000;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(212, 211, 211);
    border: thin solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
}

nav {
    grid-area: nav;
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: thin solid #000;
    align-self: center;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}


.article {
    grid-area: article;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    border: thin solid #000;
}

.article-2 {
    grid-area: article-2;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    border: thin solid #000;
}


.aside-1 {
    grid-area: aside-1;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(175, 171, 171);
    border: thin solid #000;
}

.aside-2 {
    grid-area: aside-2;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(128, 120, 120);
    border: thin solid #000;
}

.aside-3 {
    grid-area: aside-3;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(121, 112, 112);
    border: thin solid #000;
}

.aside-4 {
    grid-area: aside-4;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(102, 98, 98);
    border: thin solid #000;
}

.pct {
    background-color: rgb(194, 180, 180);
    border: thin solid #000;
    Display: grid;
    grid-area: pct;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, 200px);
    grid-template-areas: "section-1 section-2";
    grid-gap: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pct-image {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.pct-image>img {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: thin solid #222;
}

.section-1 {
    grid-area: section-1;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    align-self: center;
}

.section-2 {
    grid-area: section-2;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    align-self: center;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(36, 34, 34);
    border: thin solid #000;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 15px;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    color: rgb(240, 231, 231);
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: rgb(212, 199, 199);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu li {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 15px 5px;
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
}

.logo a {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.button.secondary {
    border-bottom: thin #444 solid;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.toggle {
    order: 1;
}

.item.button {
    order: 2;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    order: 3;
    display: none; 
}
.item.active {
    display: block;
}

.item.toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bars {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bars::before, .bars::after {
    background-color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    content: "";
}

.bars.before {
    top: 5px;
}

.bars.after {
    top: -5px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 520px) {

    .menu {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .logo {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .item.button {
        width: auto;
        order: 1;
        display: block;
    }

    .toggle {
        order: 2;
    }

    .button.secondary {
        border: 0;
    }
    .button a {
        padding: 7px 15px;
        background-color: teal;
        border: thin solid #006d6d;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .button.secondary a {
        background: transparent;
    }

    .button a:hover {
        transform: initial;
    }

    .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
        background-color: #006d6d;
        border-color: #005959;
    }

    .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .item {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
    }

    .toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    .logo {
        order: 0;
    }

    .item {
        order: 1;
    }

    .button {
        order: 2;
    }

    .menu li{
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }

    .menu li.button {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

}
```

Can anyone share any knowledge / advice with me? Thanks in advance~

Comment: What is the problem? This is just a code-dump. If this is a presentation problem, *make a minimal example focusing on that*. If this is a database problem, focus on that. Don't include CSS in a database question.

Comment: There is no "Java" (or JAVA, whatever that is) in pages. Do you mean JavaScript? If so you already have some.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: I apologize, I am pretty new to this site. I do want to focus on the display, here is a link to the page ; http://141.217.97.220/ba8585/testing/flexform.php. If you inspect in different browsers you can see what I am saying

Comment: That doesn't help either. I'm just asking for clarification on the question: Is this a database problem *or* a presentation problem relating to CSS?

Comment: this is a presentation question; why are the browsers not recognizing my grid?

Comment: Delete all the database code. It can help to make a very minimal version we can drop into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and experiment with to help with fussy CSS issues.

Comment: I Deleted the code